# whose view is not in the window hierarchy Facebook Login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have this warning I don't understand where is my error in my code

using code 7.2 and iOS 9.2

Error:

> warning: Attempt to present < VidcustCustomAppIos.VCTabBarController:
>   0x7ff838f50790 > on < FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x7ff838d8ceb0 >
>   whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```c
 @IBAction func facebookLoginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self) { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
         if (result.isCancelled) {
            print("Cancelled")
        } else {
            print("Logged in")
           let token =  FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
            VCClusterManager.sharedInstance.connectWithFacebook(token.tokenString, completion: { (isConnected, error) -> () in
                if error == nil && isConnected == true {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.segueIdentifier, sender: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not with the case of Facebook Login

You will get this warning when performing a segue from a view controller that is embedded in  container. The solution is to use segue from the parent of container, not from container's view controller.

Comment: Madhava  
What do you mean by "view controller that is embedded in container". When you say embedded in a contain, what do you exactly mean? What is it your referring to?

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**
Developers can receive this warning when performing a segue from a view controller that is embedded in container.

**Solution:** 
Use segue from the parent of container, not from container's view controller (eg. back button, next button or any buttons that you want to perform an action to transition to another view controller)